# Defining nested list into a vector with default R packages

Tags: r, list, vector, default

```
myList <- rep(0, 5)
myList <- list('Aa'= c("1","12"), 'Ba'= c("123","321"), 'Ca'= c("444"))
for (x in names(myList)) {
  for (j in myList[x]) {
    sample <- c(unlist(myList[j]))
  } }

sample
```

In a nested list, want to turn this list to a vector with the

> "for"

loop

I can't figure out how to extract the values without defining a function.

```
sample <- c(unlist(myList[x])
```

Doing "unlist" does the work just with another codes

```
> sample
 NULL
```

But I want all and this one is not working like that. Is there any basic version? No need to be fast or non-complicate. Just with only the base R distribution packages, with the

> alternative of "unlist"

if it is possible.

I need something like

> ```
>      Aa1  Aa2  Ba1  Ba2  Ca1  
>      "1" "12" "123" "444"
> ```

And i think i don't need

> myList <- rep(0, 5)

Comment: `myList[[2]][1]` extracts value `123` (the 1st) from list member `Ba` (the 2nd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right you want to unlist without `unlist` in base R. You could do it like so:

```
res <- NULL
for (i in seq(names(myList))) {
  nm <- names(myList)[i]
  l <- myList[[nm]]
  res<- c(res, setNames(l, paste0(nm, seq(l))))
}
res
# Aa1   Aa2   Ba1   Ba2   Ca1 
# "1"  "12" "123" "321" "444"
```

*Check:*

```
unlist(myList)
# Aa1   Aa2   Ba1   Ba2    Ca 
# "1"  "12" "123" "321" "444"
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I maybe don't quite understand your question right, but doesn't

```
sample <- unlist(myList)
#   Aa1   Aa2   Ba1   Ba2    Ca 
#  "1"  "12" "123" "321" "444"
```

or

```
sample <- structure(unlist(myList))
#  Aa1   Aa2   Ba1   Ba2    Ca 
#  "1"  "12" "123" "321" "444"
```

achieve what you want?

Comment: Yes it does but I need to use it with that for loop, even if I don't, let's say im not going to use it, is there any alternative way to write sample <- unlist(myList) , without unlist ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't get you question

Comment: Don't be, I'm sorry if it seems not clear. I'm banned to use "unlist" so I'm looking for an alternative to that, that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

I also have to admit to not quite understanding what you're trying to achieve, but if you want the result of `unlist()` without explicitly using that function you can try `rapply()` - although by default `unlist()` is being used under the hood:

```
rapply(myList, f = function(x) x)

  Aa1   Aa2   Ba1   Ba2    Ca 
  "1"  "12" "123" "321" "444"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you want to avoid `unlist`, but here's an alternative with `flatten_chr`.

```
len <- lengths(myList)
setNames(purrr::flatten_chr(myList),paste0(rep(names(myList),len),sequence(len)))

#  Aa1   Aa2   Ba1   Ba2   Ca1 
#  "1"  "12" "123" "321" "444"
```

If you are ok adjusting the names a bit you can also use `make.unique` :

```
setNames(purrr::flatten_chr(myList),make.unique(rep(names(myList), len),sep = ""))

#   Aa   Aa1    Ba   Ba1    Ca 
#  "1"  "12" "123" "321" "444"
```